# How to write a test in Jasmine where the object's existence is checked prior to the function call on that object?

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, if-statement, jasmine

It's easiest to describe the problem by showing a code sample.

**Code under test:**

```
function something() {
    if(this.myObject) {
        this.myObject.callMyFunction();
    }

    this.callAnotherFunction();
}
```

**Jasmine test:**

```
it("should call myObject.callMyFunction() because 'myObject' is defined") {
    spyOn(theScope, "callAnotherFunction");
    theScope.something();
    expect(theScope.myObject.callMyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled(); // a spy has already been created for theScope.myObject.callMyFunction
} // TEST PASSES

it("should not call myObject.callMyFunction() because 'myObject' is undefined") {
    spyOn(theScope, "callAnotherFunction");
    theScope.myObject = undefined;
    theScope.something();
    expect(theScope.myObject.callMyFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // a spy has already been created for theScope.myObject.callMyFunction
} // TEST FAILS
```

As you can see in the second test, I'm trying to set `theScope.myObject` to be `undefined`, but the test won't run because it's then calling `callMyFunction()` on the undefined object `theScope.myObject`.

Comment: I would argue that having a test that passes when myObject is set *and* another one that passes when myObject is not set, providing they *both* checking that callAnotherFunction is called, would be enough.

Comment: So you think that I shouldn't check that `theScope.myObject.callMyFunction` is not called?

Comment: Well, since you're setting myObject to null, if your test pass without an NPE, doesn't it prove that you did not try to call a function on it ? (otherwise you would get an NPE.) I would add an assertion checking that you actually call 'callAnotherFunction' in both cases, and that'd look enough to me. If you ever change the code, and remove the check by mistake, the latter test will fail, so you're covered against regression.